# CrossBrowser: File Upload Issue (HTML+PHP) - NOT TO UPLOAD IMMEDIATELY

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Is there a possibility to NOT upload a file IMMEDIATELY, but to store maybe in an array to upload it in a later step?

I want to ensure is that the user can navigate freely between the form pages and then upload the files in the last step. The only way I know is to encode the files and store them in the session, but this is anything other than elegant.

It should also be a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form splitted over different urls and you have a file input in a previous step no, it isn't possible.

unless...

if your "cross browser" requirements can ignore IE<10 and every non recent other browser, you may use the javascript File Api to read the file client side, eventually store it on the client with sessionStorage/localStorage and send it to you later

See

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: then you're stuck with having the users upload the files early. You don't need to store it in session though, you may also move it somewhere away from the temporary folder and keep just the path in session

Answer (score 0):

When ever the user uploaded the file then that file will be moved to the temporary location.

That temporary file will be deleted when ever the script is finishes.

In your scenario if the user moves from one page to another page then the file will be deleted automatically